# How to display only the most recent countdown timer in a Javascript game without additionally libraries?

Tags: javascript, function, countdown, overwrite

I'm creating a silly matching game. The game seems to work appropriately, including a 10 second timer for each round. I'm wanting to display a timer, so that the player knows how much time they have left. I can get it to work, but the problem is that on each level beyond the first, the timer from the previous level (if it hasn't reached 00:00) and the timer for the current level seem to overwrite each other and are each briefly displayed.

How can I go about hiding the previous level's timer when the player progresses to the next level?

I've attempted to remove the node and recreate it before calling the timer function, but to no avail.

```
// Prevent overlapping timers by creating a new tickTock div
function refreshTimer() {
  displayTimer.remove();
  var tickTock = document.createElement("div");
  tickTock.setAttribute("id", "tickTock");
  textContainer.appendChild(tickTock);
} */
```

If you run the following snippet in a full page, the correct answer to the first level will be the last image in the first row. That should reproduce the issue I'm having with the display timer.

```js
// Declare starting variables
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var gameEnd = document.getElementById("gameEnd");
var topText = document.getElementById("instructions1");
var bottomText = document.getElementById("instructions2");
var displayTimer = document.getElementById("tickTock");
var textContainer = document.getElementById("textContainer");
var numberOfJesses = 5;

// Start the game
function generateFaces() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfJesses; i++) {

    // Generate the images
    var jesse = document.createElement("img");
    // Only using a direct link, so that SO can play the game in order to reproduce the issue.
    jesse.src = "https://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/postandcourier.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/b/c2/bc2237a6-c038-11e9-940f-1b44a4174d4a/5d56c8d1dc6d2.image.png?resize=1200%2C849";
    jesse.height = "100";

    // Create random values for top location
    randomTop = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 401)) + "px";
    jesse.style.top = randomTop;

    // Create random values for left location
    randomLeft = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 401)) + "px";
    jesse.style.left = randomLeft;

    // Place the images in the left side box
    theLeftSide.appendChild(jesse);
  }

  // Copy the left side into the right side
  var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);

  // Remove the last image
  leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);

  // Place the images in the right side box
  theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

  // Select the last image on the left to be the correct choice
  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Clear the board after the correct answer is selected
    while (theLeftSide.hasChildNodes()) {
      theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
    }
    while (theRightSide.hasChildNodes()) {
      theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
    }

    // Add 5 more images for the next level
    numberOfJesses += 5;

    // Start the next level
    generateFaces();
  };

  // Reset the timer on correct answer
  // FIXME: refreshTimer();

  // Start the display timer
  goTime();
}

// Keep track of time for the display timer
function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
  this.tickFtns = [];
  this.running = false;
}

CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  if (this.running) {
    return;
  }
  this.running = true;
  var start = Date.now(),
  that = this,
  diff, obj;

  (function timer() {
    diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
  }());
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
  if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
    this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
  }
  return this;
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
  return !this.running;
};

CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
  return {
    'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
  };
};

// Set up the display timer
function goTime() {
  var timer = new CountDownTimer(10);

  timer.onTick(format).start();

  function restart() {
    if (this.expired()) {
      setTimeout(function() { timer.start(); }, 1000);
    }
  }

  function format(minutes, seconds) {
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    displayTimer.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
};

/* Unable to get this to properly affect the display timer
// Prevent overlapping timers by creating a new tickTock div
function refreshTimer() {
  displayTimer.remove();
  var tickTock = document.createElement("div");
  tickTock.setAttribute("id", "tickTock");
  textContainer.appendChild(tickTock);
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Rob Upchurch">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade|Rubik+Mono+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Jesse "The Body" Ventura's Matching Game</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="generateFaces()">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="leftImage">
        <img src="Jesse_Ventura.png" alt="Jesse Ventura" id="jesse">
      </div>
      <div class="rightImage">
        <img src="jesse2.png" alt="Jesse Ventura" id="jesse2">
      </div>
      <div class="textContainer" id="textContainer">
        <div class="text">
          <h1 id="header">Let's Play!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2 id="score"></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p class="instructions" id="instructions1">Click the image of Jesse Ventura on the left side that is missing from the right side.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p class="instructions" id="instructions2">You have 10 seconds on each round to select the correct image.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tickTock"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gameContainer">
        <div class="game" id="leftSide"></div>
        <div class="game" id="rightSide"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="gameEnd"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="matching.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm wanting the previous timer to be hidden and only have the current level's timer to be visible.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to just the part that's causing the issue; a [mre]. To reproduce this, we'll need the HTML and the JavaScript (likely only for the timer bits, since that seems to be where you're having the issue). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow.